# Add targeting when posting to a page using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to a page on facebook using the facebook API. But I want to customize the post target.

When I post to a page on facebook I get these results  :

[image]

You get Shared with : (languages...) and News feed targeting : (languages...)

But when I post to a page on my custom website using the facebook api I get these results :

[image]

I only get the News feed targeting and not the shared with...

Does anybody knows what to use to get the Shared with options using the facebook API?

To get the News feed targeting I'm using :

```
var feed_targeting = {
      'locales': ["1001", "1", "2", "4", "9"],
};
```

But I want to know what to use for the Shared with option....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed/#pubfields – there’s `feed_targeting` and `targeting`, those are two different things.

> targeting: Object that limits the audience for this content. Anyone not in these demographics will not be able to view this content.